# UIButton selection color

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm using a `UIButton` as a pressable imageView. Right now when I press the button the background image is still visible but a gray, transparent layer is on top of the image. How do I change the color of this layer?

I've tried setting the `setBackgroundImage:forState:` but all that does is replace the current image with another image.

**Note**

I'm able to do this with a tableview row using the following code:

```
// Custom selectionStyle color
UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor myBlue];
groupCell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's approach is to expect you to provide an image that is tinted accordingly. So if you wanted to change that gray overlay to red you would need to call `setBackgroundImage:forState:` and supply an appropriately tinted image that would be swapped in.

Unfortunately there is no direct access in the SDK/API that will let you change the default highlight color - just the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, that can't be done in my app because the background image of the button will be taken from the camera. It's not a big deal that I won't be able to do this but it would make for a better theme color scheme overall.

Comment: Maybe I will have to go with using an actual 'UIImageView' and setting up events to mimic a button. Assuming that I could set the background view like I did with the table cell.

Comment: Perhaps you could do some sort of compositing to create an image that uses the camera input and overlays a grey layer on top of it?

Comment: Seems like too much overhead. I would have to save all of those images to core data too. Great idea, just not for my situation.